# InvalidRequestException Invalid Client Secret - Stripe payment sdk

Tags: android, stripe-payments

I'm trying to accept payment but getting this error in callback of sdk.

Code:

```
val params = cardInputWidget.paymentMethodCreateParams
        if (params != null) {
            val confirmParams =
                ConfirmPaymentIntentParams.createWithPaymentMethodCreateParams(params, clientSecret)
            stripe = Stripe(
                applicationContext,
                PaymentConfiguration.getInstance(applicationContext).publishableKey)

            stripe.confirmPayment(this, confirmParams)
        }


override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    stripe.onPaymentResult(requestCode, data, object : ApiResultCallback<PaymentIntentResult> {
        override fun onSuccess(result: PaymentIntentResult) {
            val paymentIntent = result.intent
            val status = paymentIntent.status
            if (status == StripeIntent.Status.Succeeded) {
                val gson = GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create()
                showToast("Payment succeeded " + gson.toJson(paymentIntent))
            } else {
                showToast("Payment Error: "+paymentIntent.lastPaymentError?.message ?: "")
            }
        }

        override fun onError(e: Exception) {
            showToast("Payment failed "+e.message)
        }
    })
}
```

onError is getting always called!
This is internal code of sdk:
[image: quest]

Comment: This is going to be tricky to debug on StackOverflow. It seems to be an issue with the client secret you are sending. Either it's truncated/incorrect or maybe it's from a different Stripe account and you're using the wrong API keys? You would have more luck with Stripe's support team: https://support.stripe.com/contact

Comment: I'm using publishkey and client secret from same account still getting error. I didn't get any help from the docs and GitHub issues.

Comment: You need to init your Stripe PaymentConfiguration instance first, with PaymentConfiguration.init(
            applicationContext,
            "pk_test_TYooMQauvdEDq54NiTphI7jx"
        )

Answer (score 5):

You are using `confirmPayment` method instead of `confirmSetupIntent` method. One is used for confirming payment intents with client secret, and the other one is used for confirming setup intents with client secret. Checkout the stripe documentation for saving and reusing payment methods: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse

Comment: It wasn't exactly the answer but it helped me with the add credit card flow where confirmSetupIntent is supposed to be used. While the sample code on Stripe website for CardInputWidget is using confirmPayment.

Answer (score 0):

There was Payment Failure issue with flutter , for Flutter, Payment was not able to suceed similar issue I was facing with Stripe:

```
Stripe.publishableKey = "pk_test_RS3cXiyeMHhEmpqnojBPuukSZQdjA7S00GE5LjhtqLongSecureKey342423";
Stripe.merchantIdentifier = "acct_1IL78e48329489014f";

Stripe.stripeAccountId = "acct_1IL78e48329489014f";
Stripe.urlScheme = "flutterstripe";
await Stripe.instance.applySettings();
```

This is for flutter only. You need to specify Stripe details in main() function.